# docker failed to register layer error processing

Tags: docker, ubuntu-16.04

I've just finished to install docker on ubuntu 16.04.

My docker version is 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

I start my docker with

```
sudo service docker start
```

and it starts running. when i try to run

```
docker run hello-world
```

i get the following message

```
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally

latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
ca4f61b1923c: Extracting 
[==================================================>]     985B/985B
docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): 
invalid argument.
```

Can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Can you give us the output of docker images -a

Comment: REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE it's empty..

Comment: Seems so weird. Try this command (This is for complete docker cleanup)
 docker system prune -a
and type Y. Then retry the docker run hello-world

Comment: @Vamsi not work. Error message again.

Comment: Have you managed to perform the complete docker cleanup?

Comment: Can you try to run another docker image (like python or centos).